# SSRS report with dynamic query taking parameters defined from a database

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamic-sql

My overall goal is to produce an SSRS 2012 report which displays metrics about workers in different teams. Additionally, I would like to have some custom dropdown (customizable per team) where only particular workers are displayed.

For example, I have 2 Projects - Project1 and Project2. Project1 wants dropdown choices which allow them to show their workers in San Francisco and New York teams. Project2 wants a dropdown that allows them to show workers in Houston and San Francisco teams.

Teams are not a construct represented by data in the database. I also want to arbitrarily define custom Teams in the future (Team that works from home, Team that knows C++, etc..). The "All" team means no filtering.

The query for a project would be

```
select Member.MemberName, Member.MemberWork from Member where Member.Project='Project1'
```

For Project1, San Francisco team, I would write

```
select Member.MemberName, Member.MemberWork from Member where Member.Project='Project1' and Member.MemberID IN (123, 125, 127) /* teams are not stored in the database so I need to hardcode member IDs that compose a team */
```

The way I am storing the relationship between each custom dropdown choice is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TeamQueries] ([ProjectName] [nchar](128) NULL,
[TeamName] [nchar](64) NULL,[TeamQuery] [nchar](3096) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Example Rows in this table would be in this image (which I cannot post from lack of reputation)

The query (the dataset is called "data") in the SSRS report is as follows

```
 declare @query nvarchar(max)
    set @query= 'select Member.MemberName, Member.MemberWork from Member where Member.ProjectName=' + @ProjectDropdown + ' and Member.MemberID IN (' + @TeamQuery + ')'
    exec(@query)
```

The `@ProjectDropdown` is a single valued `TEXT` parameter with default and available values coming from a query

`select ProjectName from Projects`

The `@TeamQuery` is also a single valued `TEXT` parameter with default and available values coming from a query

```
SELECT TeamName  ,TeamQuery FROM TeamQueries
  WHERE (ProjectName=@ProjectDropdown or ProjectName = 'All')
```

Choosing Team1 and San Francisco in the available dropdowns, the error message I get is:

> Query execution failed for dataset 'data'. Incorrect syntax near
>   '127'.

The dropdowns get populated fine. By choosing Project1, I get choices of San Francisco and New York in the dropdown.

My question is - what's wrong, how do I get this to work? The general issue is I want a where predicate string (that is part of an IN clause) to come from the database and be optionally applied in SSRS.

Here are some things I have tried.

- I tried to make this construct work outside of dynamic SQL. for example, using an OR construct to avoid the `select Member.MemberID from Member` and have the following

`select Member.MemberName, Member.MemberWork from Member where member.ProjectName=@ProjectDropdown and (@TeamQuery IS NULL OR Member.MemberID IN (@TeamQuery))`

I kept getting `VARCHAR` to int conversion errors. I tried 
`select Member.MemberName, Member.MemberWork from Member where Member.ProjectName=@ProjectDropdown and (@TeamQuery IS NULL OR CONVERT(VARCHAR(Member.MemberID)) IN (@TeamQuery))`

or converting `@TeamQuery` to `INT` by `SPLIT` and making TeamQuery a multi-valued parameter.

I tried printing `@query` in SSRS with the hopes of some debuggability but I cannot see the query that SSRS is using.

If I hardcode the parameter of @TeamQuery in SSRS, the query does work. I suspect something with strings and quotes - the database is retrieving something slightly different than I am expecting (perhaps I need to strip quotes?)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the definition of the column. I mistakenly made the column definition nchar rather than nvarchar. This caused extra padding and the query error.